# VBA Cross referencing in range.formula

Tags: excel, range, formula, cross-reference, vba

Can someone help me with the implementation of this?

```
Range("B3").Formula = "=SUMIF(Active.Select!$A:$A,Results.select!$A3,Active.select!B:B)"
```

I have defined Active and Results as WorkSheet and my objective was to have a dynamic reference to them so so that the macro cna be run on any sheet of the workbook without having any kind of static referece lik Sheet1!

If i try to run what i have wrote he ask me to provide Active and Results through a open... window

I know it might be a noobish question but i am just getting started

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the sheet names then the formula will refer to the Worksheet that it is on.

```
Range("D2").Formula = "=SUMIF($A:$A,$E$1,$B:$B)"
```

[image]

Worksheets have an Evaluate method that will return the value of a formula

[image]

**Note:**  I didn't use `Range("B3").Formula = "=SUMIF($A:$A,$A3,B:B)"` because it is a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Active` and `Results` are both `Worksheet` objects, then if you wish to create a formula to go into cell B3 of the `ActiveSheet`, try this:

```
Range("B3").Formula =  "=SUMIF('" & Active.Name & "'!$A:$A,'" & Results.Name & "'!$A3,'" & Active.Name & "'!B:B)"
```

---

If you want to just obtain the value and use it for something within VBA, try this:

```
Dim sumIfResult As Double
sumIfResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Active.Range("$A:$A"),Results.Range("$A3"),Active.Range("B:B"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much the first one was exactly what i was looking for and it work like charm :-) Also the second part is extremely useful for my learning